# What is the recommended was to pull several 1000 individual records from Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have an Azure Table Store that contains minute telemetry from several hundred remote devices.  The data is partitioned by a key that concatenates device id, location id, day of year, and year.  So, as an example, if I want to pull a full month's worth of data for any given device I need to pull all the data from 30 partitions.

For one particular calculation I only need records timestamped at the top and bottom of the hour, i.e., times where the minutes are 0 and 30, respectively.  Currently, to do this I create an array of tasks to pull each record individually and grab them in parallel (for a month this is 1440 - I know the partition key and the row key of each record so I can use the TableOperation.Retrieve<>(partitionKey, rowKey) method.  The code below illustrates the approach:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<TableResult>>();
foreach (var date in dates)
{
    foreach (var timeOfDay in checkTimes)
    {
        var dateTimeLocal = date.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(timeOfDay));
        var dateTimeUtc = Helper.ConvertLocalTimeToUtcTime(location.TimeZoneId, dateTimeLocal);

        var partitionKey = location.RowKey + "_" + deviceGuid + "_" + dateTimeUtc.DayOfYear + "_" + dateTimeUtc.Year;
        var rowKey = dateTimeUtc.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:00");

        var table = TableHelper.GetTable(Data.StorageString, "table");
        var retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<DataEntities.EnergyData>(partitionKey, rowKey);
        tasks.Add(table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation));
    }
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

var demandData = tasks.Where(c => c.Result.Result != null).Select(c => (DataEntities.EnergyData)c.Result.Result).ToArray();
```

The dates array contains datetimes of midnight for each day I want to aggregate, and the checkTimes are the times of day I'm interested in each day.

For a month's worth of data (~1440 records) this approach can take much longer than just pulling every record for a month and filtering in memory on the ones I'm interested in - I expected it to be much quicker.

Any ideas on why this runs so slowly (is it a throttling issue with Table Storage for example)?  Is there a faster and more reliable approach?  I'm beginning to think that the best way is simply to make a copy of each row where the minutes are 0 or 30 into another table so I can retrieve what I need in a few larger queries.

Answer (score 0):

As [Query Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Query-Entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN) states:

> A query against the Table service may return a **maximum of 1,000 entities** at one time and may execute for a maximum of five seconds. If the result set contains more than 1,000 entities, if the query did not complete within five seconds, or if the query crosses the partition boundary, the response includes custom headers containing a set of continuation tokens. The continuation tokens may be used to construct a subsequent request for the next page of data.

Based on your scenario, you have specified the `partitionKey` and `rowKey` to retrieve the single record. Per my understanding, at this point, you client would send 1000+ requests against table service, while for [Partition Range Scan](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables/#_Queries) or [Row Range Scan](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables/#_Queries), it would send just several requests.

I assumed that it may dues to the network latency when you using Point Queries (specifying a single PartitionKey and RowKey using equality predicates). You could [enable azure storage metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-enable-and-view-metrics#how-to-enable-metrics-using-the-azure-portal) for your table storage, and check the `AverageE2ELatency` and `AverageServerLatency` metrics via [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) as follows:

[image]

For more details about table storage metrics, you could refer to [Transactions Table Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-metrics-table-schema#transactions-table-schema).

> Any ideas on why this runs so slowly (is it a throttling issue with Table Storage for example)? Is there a faster and more reliable approach? I'm beginning to think that the best way is simply to make a copy of each row where the minutes are 0 or 30 into another table so I can retrieve what I need in a few larger queries.

Per my understanding, you could leverage [Row Range Scan](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables/#_Queries) by specifying the RowKey within a month range (e.g. `rowKey>="2016-06-01T00:00:00" and rowKey<="2016-06-30T23:59:59"`) to retrieve the records for a given device, then filter in memory on the ones as you expected.

Comment: Many thanks for the info.  However, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables "Specifying both partition and row keys in a query is the fastest way to retrieve a single entity from the Table service." Each query is only retrieving a single entity so I don't think your remarks about 1000+ in a single query applies here.  I'm concerned with making 1000+ separate queries, each query requesitng a single entity.

Comment: I would recommend that you could try to diagnostic the metrics from your table service and check the `AverageE2ELatency` and `AverageServerLatency` metrics for troubleshooting this issue.